# PHPMailer Connection --> Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Success

Tags: linux, phpmailer

Getting a very weird connection error configuring a new PHPMAILER SMTP end-point. PHPMailer code,is below. I am able to connect with the same set of credentials with Thunderbird, and hence the auth and server settings info is correct, as mentioned in the PHPMailer script. With PHPMailer, getting the error,

> Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL:
> Success
> [/var/www/html/phpmailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line
> 468] SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Has anyone experienced this same issue?

Running an Ubuntu 20.04 server with PHP 7.4.

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.example.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 5;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'test@example.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secretpassword';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
//    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`
//$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;  

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('test@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('receiver@test.com', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient

    //Attachments
//    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
//    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
'verify_peer' => false,
'verify_peer_name' => false,
'allow_self_signed' => true
)
);
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

My SMTPDebug output

```
2022-02-28 14:26:53 Connection: opening to smtp.example.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ),)
2022-02-28 14:26:53 Connection: opened
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "220 example.local Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 28 Feb 2022 15:30:07 +0100"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 example.local Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 28 Feb 2022 15:30:07 +0100
2022-02-28 14:26:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO example.website.com
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "250-example.local Hello [123.123.123.123]"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 62914560"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "250-STARTTLS"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "250-AUTH LOGIN"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "250 XRDST"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-example.local Hello [123.123.123.123]250-SIZE 62914560250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-STARTTLS250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS250-AUTH LOGIN250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 XRDST
2022-02-28 14:26:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP INBOUND: "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready"
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2022-02-28 14:26:53 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Success [/var/www/html/phpmailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 468]
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2022-02-28 14:26:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2022-02-28 14:26:53 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
2022-02-28 14:26:53 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Comment: Are you sure that port 587 is correct? Maybe port 443 instead would be more successful?

Comment: No, port 587 is normal for the SMTP submission port. 443 is for HTTPS, which PHPMailer doesn't support.

Comment: I recommend trying again with the latest version of PHPMailer (6.6.0) which I just released today. It provides more info when you get a TLS-related error, and that might shed more light on what's going wrong for you here.

Comment: @Synchro, I will do that and share the findings. Thank you.

Comment: @Synchro

Updated to PHPMailer 6.6.0 and now I have an additional line which is

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Success

I am sure this message was in the old version as well.. Any thoughts?

Comment: OK, there are no good clues there. You can see that the STARTTLS command is successful, and it fails immediately afterwards when `stream_socket_enable_crypto` is called, which suggests that you might be missing some protocol support, or have local misconfiguration. There is [an issue about this exact message](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/153) that might help.